# Possible British Summertime bug?

Tags: support, time, timezone, consecutive-days

I'm wondering can anyone reproduce this error. If I visit SO after 12 midnight the calendar on my user profile doesn't show I have visited that new day. Even though the *last seen* field reports accurately! I think this is something to do with British Summertime, as this error has only appeared since the clocks went forward. I'm based in Ireland, could this be confusing the system?

[image: screen shot]

Comment: If you're in Ireland it's called IST (Irish Standard Time) rather than BST...

Comment: I am tired of these time questions. None of them actually matter.

Comment: @bjb568: How so? It's a legitimate question, and could easily be mistaken as a bug.

Comment: @Matt If the system replaced every time with 'derpderpderp', I wouldn't care. It's as annoying as the pluralization "bugs". Somebody needs to bring out a giant clock to bang these people with :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BST 00:00 is UTC 23:00; 1 hour too early for there to be a new Stack Overflow day.

All site actions are measured by UTC time, not local time. Because UK wintertime (GMT) happens to coincide with UTC you were probably mislead into thinking local time applies.

Click on the *Achievements* icon in the top bar to see the current UTC time.

Answer (score 5):

Everything on Stack Exchange is based on UTC time, and not localized to you (e.g. BST).

00:00 BST is still 23:00 UTC, so your activity won't count as a new "day" until 01:00 BST.

For more info, see [What is an SE "day"? When does each day start?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start)